# Group models with exact same has_many through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql

Forgive me if this has been asked before, I had a hard time thinking of good search queries.

Lets say I have 2 models, Posts and Tags. Posts have many tags through a pivot model, PostTags.

What I'd like to do is group posts that have the exact same combination of tags. I know how to group posts that have any of the same tags, but I've been having a harder time with this.

For example, if I have a post with and ID of 1, and the post has two Tags- one with an ID of 5, another with an ID of 7. I would have 2 PostTags, one with a post_id of 1, and a tag_id of 5, and then another with a post_id of 1 and a tag_id of 7. I have another Post with an id of 3, and it also has 2 PostTags - one with a post_id of 3 and a tag_id of 5, and another with a post_id of 3 and a tag_id of 7. I'd like to group these together so that I can get a count of how many posts have both of these tags, and no others.

Thanks, and I hope I was able to explain this properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably do something like this in a nested query:

```
SELECT tag_ids,
       string_agg(post_id, ',')
FROM (
  SELECT post_id,  
         string_agg(tag_id, ',') as tag_ids
  FROM post_tags
  GROUP BY post_id)
GROUP BY tag_ids;
```

**Explanation:**

First in the inside query, you concatenate tag_ids grouped by post_id, so you can get the combination of tags for each post.

Then in the outside query, you concatenate post_ids by the combination of tag_ids, so you get all the post_ids for each tag combination.

This might not be the end yet, you could further process the post ids, or modify the query to fetch whatever data you need.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope the Model relationships are sets properly.

```
# Post Model
class Post
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :post_tags
end

# Fetch Tags to match with posts collection
tag_ids = []

# Query to fetch posts
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: tag_ids }).
  group("posts.id").having("count(posts.id) >= ?", tag_ids.size)
```

1. First line ensure that only posts having tags included in the specified
   tag list are fetched
2. Second line ensure that posts are having both of the tags.
3. If you want to match for exact tags (no other tags should present), then
   change the condition to `=` instead of `>=`

Happy Hacking!